# How to reduce codes numbers

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am new in Arduino projects, i made a digital counter that counts from 00 to 99.
Here is my code below

```
void setup()
{
pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
/* segment starts from 00*/
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
/* segment will now be 10, the 0 will continue counting up to 1*/

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);
/* the segment will now be 20 */

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);
digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
digitalWrite(5,LOW);

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
digitalWrite(6,HIGH);

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(5,LOW);

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
/* the segment will now be 9 0 */

digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(0,LOW);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
digitalWrite(2,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
/* when it gets here the segment resets to 00*/
}
```

[image: arduino counter]
It works pretty fine but the problem i have is the code is too long, is there a method i can use to reduce the length of the codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are writing here is some sort of binary counter: a BCD
(binary-coded decimal) counter to be precise. It turns out that the
processor inside the Arduino already works in binary. It's its native
language, so you do not have to tell it how to do binary. You just have
to know what operators to use in order to access the individual bits.

My approach would be to write a function that can display any number `n`
between 0 and 99. The first step is to do the decimal decomposition:
divide by 10, and take the quotient (first digit) and the remainder
(second digit). These digits will be represented in binary within the
machine. The next step is to access the individual bits. This is a two
step process:

1. Shift the bits of the number to the right until the bit you want is
   at the far right. This is accomplished with the right-shift operator.
2. Compute the bitwise AND with the number 1 (0000000000000001 in
   binary). This will clear all the bits but the one you want, and
   result in either 0 (the same as `LOW`) or 1 (i.e. `HIGH`).

For example, if you want to get bit 1 of the number 7, you do

```
0000000000000111 = 7  initial number
0000000000000011 = 3  shifted one potion to the right
0000000000000001 = 1  bitwise AND-ed with 1
```

In code:

```cpp
void display(int n)
{
    int digit0 = n % 10;
    int digit1 = n / 10;
    digitalWrite(0, (digit0 >> 0) & 1);
    digitalWrite(1, (digit0 >> 1) & 1);
    digitalWrite(2, (digit0 >> 2) & 1);
    digitalWrite(3, (digit0 >> 3) & 1);
    digitalWrite(4, (digit1 >> 0) & 1);
    digitalWrite(5, (digit1 >> 1) & 1);
    digitalWrite(6, (digit1 >> 2) & 1);
    digitalWrite(7, (digit1 >> 3) & 1);
}
```

**Edit**: If you need more that 2 digits, you have to successively
divide by 10:

1. Divide the number to be displayed by 10: the rest of the division is
   the rightmost digit
2. replace the original number by the quotient of the division
3. divide again by 10: the rest of the division is the second rightmost
   digit
4. replace the original number by the quotient of the division
5. etc.

For example, for three decimal digits:

```cpp
void display(int n)
{
    int digits[3];  // digits[0] is the rightmost digit
    digits[0] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    digits[1] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    digits[2] = n % 10;

    // Now make sure that n < 10 (otherwise we are missing digits),
    // then display digits[0], digits[1] and digits[2].
}
```

The main program now only has to loop through the numbers 0 to 99, and
display each one in turn:

```cpp
void loop()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        display(n);
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot although I have little knowledge on it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.But how did you get digit0=n%10  digit1=n/10, and if i want to add another bcd to it what calculations do i need to make to get it i have been trying digit2=n/100 but it didnt work well.

Comment: @JosephAfodu: Re “_how did you get digit0=n%10 [...]_”: I learned decimal counting in primary school, and then I learned the meaning of the `/` and `%` operators in C++. Re “_and if i want to add another bcd_”: see amended answer.

Comment: @JosephAfodu, The greater part of your confusion may be in not recognizing `%` as something you're [probably already familiar with](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/arithmetic-operators/remainder/) which is not conventional in math but is fairly conventional in coding.  You'll need to be familiar with the bitwise [operators](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/) as well.

Comment: Is there a way i can make it with 3 bcd's without the middle one displaying letters , I tried but when the last one counts 1, the middle one will be displaying letters.

Comment: @JosephAfodu: You must have a mistake in your code. If you compute `digits[1]` as `n % 10`, it should not display letters, unless the wiring is wrong.

Comment: If i do it that way digit[0] and digit[1] will show the same number at a time

Comment: If i need number 999 i use: digit0=n%10; digit1=n/10; digit2=n/100; . Also i changed : for (int n=0; n<100; n++) to for (int n=0; n<1000; n++) because i need numbers up to 999. When it gets to 99 and the third bcd shows 1, insted of the second to show 0, it will show A until it counts to f before it restarts at 1 and maybe by then the 3rd  bcd have already shown 2. Which will make the numbers not get to 999 when it gets to 930 it will restarts from 000. I just need to get rid of the letters displaying on the second bcd.

Comment: @JosephAfodu: See my edit from two days ago: the code right after “For example, for three decimal digits”.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look up how to do loops in a C or C++ programming tutorial. For example you can replace:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
}
```

with:

```
void setup()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
}
```

Comment: Also, what Edgar Bonet said. :)